# Magento 1.9 hacked. What to do?

Tags: security, magento, magento-1.9

Recently we began to experience attacks in our Magento 1.9 store. Can someone help us how to detect the entry point and how to fix it?

These are the files affected by the malware.

[Files affected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0JMY.jpg)

The files are injected with some encoded base 64, that send data to this address: https://103.233.11.28/analytics.php

Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps restore from backup before the hack?

Comment: Hi @jspcal Yes, a git reset hard restored the files... but we neet to find the breach and fix it.

Comment: You may consider upgrade M1 to OpenMage, which provides security fixes, along with many improvements.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful: https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/joe-editor-deadjoe-file/

Comment: Hello, kiatng. Thanks for the input. We are starting to upgrade our websites to OpenMage.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to determine the root cause just with this input, I do not think someone can answer to question like this

You need to analyze access logs and finding the steps hackers take and implement the patch. It's not necessary Magento - could be environmental issue as well

As Magento 1 is not supported anymore it's better to upgrade to Magento 2

Comment: Hi bxN5. Unfortunately we cannot upgrade to Mage 2 because we have a ton of custom modules that are incompatible. But we are migrating to OpenMage. I believe that this may help. Also, looking the logs, the hacker deleted his tracks...logs are clean